Load cycler circuit analysis
Hello I am attempting to build a simple load cycler that will charge and discharge 3.7 V 18650 batteries for a certain number of cycles.
I would like to program it to do something like this:

I'm not really good at electronics and would like to know if the circuit I am trying to make will work in performing out the program above:

I have a two channel relay to switch between the charging and discharging and I have the A1 analog pin to measure the voltage of the battery. I am not testing any batteries above 5V so I'm guessing I don't need any voltage dividers in the circuit.

"I would like to know if the circuit I am trying to make will work for my purpose" what exactly is that purpose?

I simply want to charge and recharge the battery for a certain number of cycles.

I edited my post to be clearer, I just want to be able to program the circuit to do what the diagram says but im not sure if ive wired everything correctly

Just a tip for future posts, you can make your own schematic with the embedded CircuitLab editor, accessible when you are writing/editing your question(it looks like a tiny circuit icon). It makes schematics much tidier and easier to read.

I see thank you for the advice, will do on future posts. As for the post, have I wired everything correctly so that I can program it to follow the diagram? Or are there some mistakes with the circuit? I would appreciate some feedback on it thx

You might more simply connect the battery to either load or charger as shown here.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

hello thank you for your reply, would my current circuit work or would I need to implement this change for it to work? Thank you

You have two SPDT relays, which gives you the possibility of connecting the load and the charger at the same time -- is that what you want?  You have to make sure your code does both relays to get the behaviour you described (either the charger or the load.  Additionally, you have low-side switching on load and charger, which is almost always okay but many find more confusing.  Why did you do it that way?

For your first question, are you saying that as long as I code it right then it should be okay to have the two SPDT relays connecting the load and charger at the same time? For the second question, I'm not sure what you mean by low-side switching but I just tried to follow a similar circuit online.

No: I mean your circuit is able to join the charger and the load and the battery if you energise both relays.  And I ask: is this what you want (it's not what you describe.)  ("Low-side switching" = "switch is on the negative wire of the load/supply")

Can't I choose which one to energise in the code? Also I'm not sure what switch you're talking about in the circuit.

Yes of course you choose in the code. My point is simply that it is possible to energise both relays which is either a benefit or a risk depending on what you want.  By "switch" I mean the contacts in the relay.
